# node.js angular.js get port from config

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, rest, express

In my root directory, I have a config.json file that contains the port that the web server should listen to. This makes it easier for anyone using the app, but I can't GET/POST without knowing the port.

I can't access the config.json file as it's in my root directory while the AngularJS controllers are in a deeper directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Angular app makes relative calls, it shouldn't need to be specified.  If you can't make all relative calls, then create a route that supplies Angular config, and call that relatively.

Comment: I've looked into local paths, I've read that I can't make calls to files outside the current directory, at least not in chrome. I can't make a route because I don't know what the port will be, so I can't call it without knowing the port for the webserver

Comment: You can get the port of the connected website from the navigator on the client side, but you really shouldn't need it.   And you can *absolutely* make calls outside of your current directory, you just can't make cross host calls without further configuration.

Comment: It actually worked. Can I just do calls on any local path? Like /test and it would call http://server.com:port/test?

Comment: Yep.  That's exactly the idea.  :-)  You can now safely ignore protocol, host and port portions of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative URLs or `var full = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');`

Comment: I can't make calls to files outside the current directory.